What happens to the charges in an inductor when you induce a voltage?
Say you have two inductors, and - very much like a transformer - you connect the first one to a voltage source, then place the other one close to it, so that there will be an emf induced by the change in magnetic flux. However, the second inductor is not connected to anything and, hence, there can be no current. So what is the behavior of the surface charges and the charges inside the coil? Do the surface charges get physically separated, i.e., does the inductor become polarized like a material that's been charged by induction? What about the inner charges? Could there actually be a current, albeit a possibly very brief one? If the changing magnetic field induces an electric field, then I'd expect these to happen. If not, then what exactly happens and what does it even mean for the inductor to have voltage if nothing's really changed in its structure?

"the second inductor is not connected to anything and, hence, there can be no current" is wrong.


So what is the behavior of the surface charges and the charges inside the coil?

Both inner and surface charges will behave the same way (except at high frequencies, due to the skin effect. That's a bit beyond your question however).
You're never going to get any strange behaviours where the surface charges go in different direction from the charges inside the metal.

Do the surface charges get physically separated, i.e., does the inductor become polarized like a material that's been charged by induction? What about the inner charges?

Yes actually, the inductor will get polarized! You'll be inducing a (small) amount of current in the coil. This current will have nowhere to go however. As a result, the charges will accumulate near the ends of the coil. Since the magnetic field is caused by a presumably AC source, the field will eventually swap directions, and then the same thing will happen in the opposite direction.
You can imagine it like there's an extremely tiny capacitor connecting the two ends of the coil.

Could there actually be a current, albeit a possibly very brief one?

See above, but yes, there is a small current! Brief might not be the correct description, because it will have the same frequency as the AC source inducing the change.

If the changing magnetic field induces an electric field, then I'd expect these to happen. If not, then what exactly happens and what does it even mean for the inductor to have voltage if nothing's really changed in its structure?

Your intuition here is generally correct. Essentially, you get positive charge at one half of the coil, and negative charge at the other half, in sort of a gradient. This goes hand-in-hand with the existence of an electric field, and also a voltage.

That is a marvelous and enlightening answer, thank you so much


However, the second inductor is not connected to anything and, hence,
there can be no current.

There is no load current if nothing is connected to the second coil. But if an ac voltage is applied to the first coil, there is current in the second coil since the mobile charge carriers (electrons) will move back and forth in response to the changing magnetic field, in order to produce an alternating polarity emf across the second coil.

So what is the behavior of the surface charges and the charges inside
the coil?

The distribution of the electrons between the surface and inner regions of the conductor will depend on the frequency of the ac voltage applied to the first coil. See Skin Effect here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect
Hope this helps.

If you connect to an ac source you have an ac current in the second wire , same as in a larger transformer ,if you connect to a dc source you have no effect on the second wire except in the first moment of connecting the dc source .
